# Stream binary file with http post

Tags: node.js, node-request

I'm using the request library to send a binary (pdf) file in the body of the request using http post  (NOTE: This API does not accept multi-part forms).  However, I have only been able to get it to work using `fs.readFilesync()`.  For some reason, when I try to use `fs.createReadStream()` the pdf file is still sent, **but it is empty**, and **the request never finishes** (I never get a response back from the server).

Here is my working version using `fs.readFileSync()`:

```
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

const filename = 'test.pdf';

request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8083/api/v1/endpoint',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json',
        'Content-Disposition': `file; filename="${filename}"`
    },
    encoding: null,
    body: fs.readFileSync(filename)
}, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log('error:', error);
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.parse(response.body.toString()));
    }
});
```

If I try to replace the body with the below, it doesn't work:

```
body: fs.createReadStream(filename)
```

I have also tried piping the http request on to the stream, like it says in the request library docs, but I get the same result:

```
fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(request({...}))
```

I've tried to monitor the stream by doing the following:

```
var upload = fs.createReadStream('test.pdf');

upload.pipe(req);

var upload_progress = 0;
upload.on("data", function (chunk) {
    upload_progress += chunk.length
    console.log(new Date(), upload_progress);
})

upload.on("end", function (res) {
    console.log('Finished');
    req.end();
})
```

I see progress for the stream and `Finished`, but still no response is returned from the API.

I'd prefer to create a read stream because of the benefits of working better with larger files, but am clueless as to what is going wrong.  I am making sure I'm not altering the file with any special encoding as well.

Is there some way to get some kind of output to see what process is taking forever?

**UPDATE:**

I decided to test with a simple 1 KB `.txt` file.  I found that it is still empty using `fs.createReadStream()`, however, this time I got a response back from the server.  The test PDF I'm working with is 363 KB, which isn't outrageous in size, but still... weren't streams made for large files anyway?  Using `fs.readFileSync()` also worked fine for the text file.

I'm beginning to wonder if this is an synchronous vs asynchronous issue.  I know that `fs.readFileSync()` is synchronous.  Do I need to wait until `fs.createReadStream()` finishes before trying to append it to the body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this working by doing the following:

```
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

const filename = 'test.pdf';

const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);

let chunks = [];
readStream.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk));
readStream.on('end', () => {
    const data = Buffer.concat(chunks);

    request({
        url: 'http://localhost:8083/api/v1/endpoint',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json',
            'Content-Disposition': `file; filename="${filename}"`
        },
        encoding: null,
        body: data
    }, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('error:', error);
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.parse(response.body.toString()));
        }
    });
});
```

I chunked the data together and concatenated it with a buffer before making the request.

I noticed in [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) it said this:

> The Buffer class was introduced as part of the Node.js API to enable interaction with octet streams in TCP streams, file system operations, and other contexts.

The API I'm calling requires the `application/octet-stream` header, so I need to use the buffer rather than streaming it directly.